# Getting pointer from uintptr_t/intptr_t - how to check if the object is valid

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pointers, casting

I'm passing uintptr_t that represents result of `new SomeClass;` between threads. For obtaining the object I use

```
   void foo(uintptr_t n)
    {
      SomeClass *p = reinterpret_cast<SomeClass *>(n);
    }
```

It works fine, but I can't think of a wat to to check if `p` is a valid object, as if somehow foo will be called with value that doesn't correspont to a memory address of my SomeClass object I will get invalid pointer.

As far as I know using void* also have this issue.

Comment: There is no way, you need to ensure it yourself. Preferably, don't use casts at all.

Comment: " if somehow foo will be called with value that doesn't correspont to a memory address of my SomeClass object I will get invalid pointer."  That's right.  So, you'd better design your program so that `foo` **isn't** ever called with anything that doesn't correspond to the address of a `SomeClass` object.

Comment: Afaik the only reliable way to do it would be to maintain an unordered_set (or similar) of currently-valid object-addresses, and see if your pointer is a present in that table before trying to use it.  Of course if you’re going to do that, there’s no need to use pointers at all; you could instead hand out unique ID numbers and then look up the corresponding pointers in an unordered_map when necessary.

Comment: Can you change the design of `foo()` to accept a `SomeClass*` (or better, a `SomeClass&`) instead of a `uinptr_t`?